# How source a set stocks from yahoo?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a stock list and a tempting consultancy to set a quote for everyone. And create a dataframe to proceed with analysis

```
result= [['ABEV3.SA', 'AZUL4.SA', 'B3SA3.SA', 'BBAS3.SA', 'BBDC3.SA', 'BBDC4.SA', 'BBSE3.SA', 'BEEF3.SA', 'BPAC11.SA']
```

[image]

```
for t in result:
    ticker[t]=wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2020-10-1')['High','Low','Open','Close','Volume','Adj Close']
```

KeyError: ('High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close')

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and not screenshots of your code.

Comment: The code is converting the column list to a single tuple and searching for that column in the data.It does not seem this syntax supports multiple column selection. Try selecting a single column first.

Comment: @mike67 how a I can  do it?  I'm a python beginner. Can yoo telll more, with an example, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataReader` returns a pandas dataframe so you need to access the data cells accordingly.

Try this code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

result= ['ABEV3.SA', 'AZUL4.SA', 'B3SA3.SA', 'BBAS3.SA', 'BBDC3.SA', 'BBDC4.SA', 'BBSE3.SA', 'BEEF3.SA', 'BPAC11.SA']

for t in result:
    x = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2020-10-1')  # return entire dataset for this stock
    print('\nStock =',t)
    print(x)  # print dataset
    print('First High =', x.iloc[0]['High'])  # get High column from first row
```

Output

```
Stock = ABEV3.SA
             High    Low   Open  Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date
2020-10-01  12.78  12.48  12.55  12.70  20845400      12.70
2020-10-02  12.83  12.53  12.61  12.53  18790500      12.53
First High = 12.779999732971191

Stock = AZUL4.SA
                 High    Low   Open      Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date
2020-10-01  26.080000  24.83  25.32  25.700001  20951400  25.700001
2020-10-02  25.559999  24.25  25.40  24.270000  14473800  24.270000
First High = 26.079999923706055

........
```